# Azure Servicebus BrokeredMessage

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have a situation where I receive a message from the bus and (due to legacy code) the code executed might take 10 minutes to run (don't beat me up for this it's all 3rd party WCF calls).

The issue here is a message lock can't be more than 5 minutes I think (and with good reasons) so, I'm thinking of getting the message, deserialising it, inspecting if it's going to be long running or not, and if so marking it as 'Completed' with the `Complete()` method.

Now here's where the internals of the client come into play. To avoid thread starvation I don't want to:

1. Receive the message (lets call this the client thread)
2. Marked the message `Completed` in the client thread
3. Start a separate thread to process my slow logic
4. Have the client thread exit as there's nothing left here to do

That could obviously result in thread starvation as more and more messages arrive to be processed.

So what I'm looking to find out is, if the following occurs

1. Receive the message (lets call this the client thread)
2. Marked the message `Completed` in the client thread
3. Process my slow logic in the client thread
4. Have the client thread exit as there's nothing left here to do

This seems logical, but does anyone know if, the moment I say this message is `Completed` will the next message arrive, or will the client wait for this client thread to exit (even though the message is marked as `Completed` and could now be deemed not to be processing a message) before it gets the next one?

Comment: Or is there a good case for using `BrokeredMessageContext `, timers and `BrokeredMessage.RenewLock()`